# Short audio playback is muted, requires warming up or secondary audio in background

Tags: arch-linux, audio, alsa, pulseaudio

I have noticed this happens both in my ArchLinux PC as well as in my ArchLinux MacBook. I need to get application notifications through short audio tones and I've figured out that it's not an issue due to notifying applications but the system itself, and it happens in both systems which are widely different.

When I play a short audio file, like `paplay /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/message.oga` I don't hear it the first time I play it.

If I play it again in sequence, I hear it and it's played correctly, at all times I repeat it in sequence.

If I wait around 10 seconds to play it again, it's muted (like in the beginning): it sounds only when warming up.

The same happens for `aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Left.wav`, but as it's a longer tone, the issue happens just on the start of the file. At first I only hear "t left", missing "fron". Afterwards I hear it in full and clear: "front left". If I wait 10 seconds, "t left" again.

The issue doesn't happen if I'm playing a music file in the background in a media player. It happens only when the computer is not playing any sound.

How to fix this? (except for keeping the PC playing an inaudible sound in daemon in the background to keep it warmed up always)

Relevant test session where the problem persists solely using alsa:

```
~ ❯❯❯ sudo mv /usr/bin/pulseaudio /usr/bin/pulseaudio.bak
~ ❯❯❯ pulseaudio.bak --kill
W: [pulseaudio.bak] main.c: Couldn't canonicalize binary path, cannot self execute.
~ ❯❯❯ paplay /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/message.oga
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
~ ❯❯❯ ps axu | grep -i pulse
francis+ 31563  0.0  0.0  10796  2144 pts/2    S+   14:35   0:00 grep --color=auto -i pulse

~ ❯❯❯ aplay -D plughw:0,7 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Left.wav
Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Left.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono

~ ❯❯❯ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: Generic Analog [Generic Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
~ ❯❯❯ lspci -nn | grep -i audio
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a2f0]
```

### UPDATE

After Linux kernel 4.11.2, [ALC1220 codec is in](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362223/initial-short-audio-playback-is-muted-requires-warming-up-or-secondary-audio-in#comment642708_362376):

```
~ ❯❯❯ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1220 Analog [ALC1220 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC1220 Digital [ALC1220 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I've connected my headphones and managed to reproduce the issue just using `aplay` but differently:

```
~ ❯❯❯ aplay -D plughw:0,0 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Left.wav
~ ❯❯❯ aplay -D plughw:0,0 /usr/share/sounds/purple/alert.wav
~ ❯❯❯ aplay -D plughw:0,0 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Left.wav
~ ❯❯❯ aplay -D plughw:0,0 /usr/share/sounds/purple/alert.wav
...
```

I had to play different audio files residing in different directories, both playbacks are cut at the start if one is played and then the other, interval between playbacks doesn't matter. If a file is played once, playing files in the same directory afterwards will not reproduce the issue, nor waiting for it to "cool down" (I've wait 1 minute). Same happens with `paplay` when turning on pulseaudio. When playing through HDMI, it reproduces in both test cases.

### UPDATE 2

Lazy as I am, I didn't report this to ALSA developers, yet, but, I've create a [user systemd unit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User):

```
[Unit]
Description=Continuous silence

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/play -qn

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Just save it to `~/.config/systemd/user/continuous-silence.service` and enable it with `systemctl --user enable continuous-silence`.

Comment: First step is to pinpoint what's causing it. Assuming you are running Pulseaudio, use `paplay` to play a wav file. If the effect persists, stop Pulseaudio and use `aplay` with a wav file. After that, you should know if it's ALSA, Pulseaudio, or a layer above.

Comment: @dirkt updated the question.

Comment: Just to make sure: You stopped Pulseaudio before using `aplay`, and verified with `ps axu`? I.e., `pasuspender`, or `pulseaudio --kill`, or whatever Arch Linux needs? If you didn't, `aplay` will still use Pulseaudio through the compatbility layer. Any messages in `dmesg` or `syslog`? If you can't hear the first part at all, maybe the initial data is dropped for some reason. If you do hear it at lower volume, I have currently no explanation.

Comment: @dirkt to really make sure I've stopped pulseaudio and it didn't restart I've renamed the binary to `/usr/bin/pulseaudio.bak` and then stopped the current running instance. There's no pulseaudio in the process list. After this `aplay` doesn't play any sound: it's muted.

Comment: @dirkt not sure if relevant, I'm using Gnome 3.

Comment: ... and `aplay` works again (with the issue) after restoring the file and executing `pulseaudio --start`.

Comment: Please edit question with output of `aplay -l`. Pick the correct device, and do `pasuspender -- aplay -D plughw:X,Y audio_file.wav`, where `X` is the card number and `Y` the device number of the device you can hear (e.g. `plughw:1,0`). Pulseaudio uses ALSA to control the hardware, so `aplay` not working while Pulseaudio does is impossible :-) While we are at it, also include output of `lspci -nn | grep -i audio`, or `lsusb` if your soundcard is USB based.

Comment: @dirkt I've just edited the question with a bit of more information which may be useful. I did this new testing thinking about an issue starting up/powering up the sound system, or it entering any powersaving state. Reading your request now.

Comment: @dirkt updated. I don't get any audio related error on `dmesg` or `journalctl`.

Comment: So no sound at all with `pasuspender ... aplay ...`, correct? What exactly is your sound setup, since you are using HDMI? Monitor with sound? TV? Home audio system? Are you sure HDMI1 is the correct one (also try HDMI0)? The numbers are not the same as the `xrandr` output numbers. As it's HDMI, my suspicion is that something at the other end needs to "wake up" and doesn't when the first audio is sent. So it drops that, and only plays the following audio batches. So, also try changing settings at whatever receives the audio.

Comment: @dirkt at the moment it's just my TV audio. The HDMI output that was tried is correct, while tested I've tried the others and they don't output anything. There's just my TV connected to the PC. Tomorrow I'm gonna try it with a headphone. The issue is, I have always experienced this on Linux. I'm counting years I've noticed this issue going through two laptops and now my new PC. Only now I'm pinpointing it. On the Windows partition in this same PC this issue doesn't happen.

Comment: I had been successfully using this method with a systemd service, but recently it’s stopped working. When I run the same command as myself, it works. My issue seems to be only with HDMI (output to a receiver) though I’ve had the same with S/PDIF. There is no latency with headphones and any program that adds buffering only has a problem on first play — with short files VLC can have this problem every time. Firefox shows the problem; Chromium does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that the receiving sound system needs to "wake up" before it output sounds, and it only does so *after* receiving the initial batch of sound data, dropping the first batch, if this can't be fixed in the receiving sound system, a workaround is to continously output silence, for example with `play` from `sox`:

```
play -n
```

**Edit**

With the additional information that it works on Windows, and the information that neither the soundcard ("Intel Corporation Device") nor the Codec ("Generic") is recognized by name, it's also possible that is is some driver issue. There's a "keep alive enable" (KAE) bit in the Codec, maybe this needs to be set, possibly by a mixer control, but I don't know enough about this.

File a bug with the ALSA developers, provide the `lspci -nn` information, and the output of `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec\#*`. (You can also put the output of the latter into a pastebin and edit your question with the link, so I can have a look).

Comment: Thanks for this tip but I have excluded this solution in the question itself.

Comment: As expected... this fix the problem... I just can't believe I'll have to put this in the background to circumvent it, this feels so hacky.

Comment: For now I'll be using `play -qn` on autostart ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I'm guessing soundcard and codec is not being recognized now because I'm on a Z270 motherboard with SupremeFX S1220 Audio CODEC (ALC1220 I guess). [Support is on 4.11](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.11#head-9a0cab7c1ef8e047458ae7fb329c2dd3b8406949) which should arrive on ArchLinux in the coming hours/days.

Comment: Looked at the [ALC1220 patch](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=a535ad57d0e6b959cd79914a1127caade36a9459), not that much change, but worth a try. Please leave a comment after you tested it, I'm curious.

Comment: Updated the question with new information. I guess only thing left is a bug report to ALSA development.

Answer (score 0):

Another fix for me happened when I started adopting Jack Audio Connection Kit coupled with pulseaudio-jack, instead of bare pulseaudio.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by following the wiki on howto setup low-latency audio

- Follow Section 1.1 on the wiki https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Professional_audio
- Do Not Install linux-rt AUR kernel
- Rebooting after completing Section 1.1 should eliminate the latency
- If not then proceed with the rest of the wiki and configuring JACK

Comment: Are there points that you can summarize from the Arch Wiki link into your answer so that your answer is self-contained? Thank you!